# Populate google bar chart on a blade view dynamically using laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-visualization, laravel-blade

I'm following a Laravel with Shopify REST API tutorial.

There I'm trying to add a simple google bar chart to indicate dates of the month V number of sales

So my
X axis -> Dates of the month
Y axis -> Number of sales of the day

E.g.:

```
2022-12-01 -> 3 
2022-12-02 -> 7
2022-12-03 -> 1
.....
2022-12-31 -> 9
```

From my controller, I get the dates of the month as follows,

```
$list=array();
$month = 12;
$year = 2022;

for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
        $list[]=date('Y-m-d', $time);
}

$new_list = implode(",",$list);
```

and I get the sales using Shopify REST.

```
$tot_o = $result_1['count'];
```

Then I passed them to my blade view.

And in my blade, I tried inserting the Google chart as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Date", "Sales", { role: "style" } ],
            [{{ $dates }}, {{ $sales }}, "#b87333"]
        ]);
              
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([
            0, 
            1, 
            {calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"}, 
            2
        ]);
              
        var options = {
            title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
            width: 600,
            height: 200,
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: { position: "none" },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
</script>
```

But this outputs me an empty chart...

Now my question is,

How can I pass those controller values to the chart on my blade and populate the chart correctly?

Comment: any errors in the browser's console? (press F12)

Comment: no errors on the console... just want to know how to populate my chart with controller..